# Как очистить очередь setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, settimeout

Всё, сдаюсь, не смог ничего нагуглить, пробую формулировать: пусть есть кнопка

```
$("#boxcard div")
```

есть слушатель кнопки

```
$(startBtn).on('click',function(){
  //после нажатия запускаем
  startGame(setTimeout(defaultState,2000)
)}
```

На самом деле всё работает, функция отрабатывается, всё хорошо, но бесит, если нажимать на кнопку 100500 раз, то этих запланированных setTimeout-ов исполнится также 100500 раз, как это можно решить? Я знаю в jquery есть что-то типа метода `stop()`, это кажется, с этим как-то связано, но я бы хотел понять как это решается на нативном уровне, и почему это вообще происходит?
Как можно сделать так чтобы если я нажал один раз - setTimeout исполнился один раз, но если я буду очень часто кликать, чтобы в очереди не скапливались эти запланированные функции, а то это похоже на какой-то глюк, спасибо)

Comment: Вам не надо очищать очередь, а надо дать таймеру сработать, не ставя в очередь новых таймеров. Сделать это можно с использованием булевского флага. Я думаю, что этот вопрос - не дубликат, во всяком случае, не дубликат указанного в ссылке.

Comment: @Igor, как такое реализовать?
Проверять сколько раз нажали на кнопку что ли? Можно пример?

Comment: `var waiting = false; $(startBtn).on('click',function(){ if (!waiting) { waiting = true; setTimeout(function(){ waiting = false; ...}, 2000); }
});`

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сделать глобальную переменную

```
var timer;
```

Передать номер создаваемого таймера этой переменной:

```
timer=setTimeout(defaultState,2000)
```

И тогда в нужном месте (в вашем случае перед вызовом `setTimeout`) можно будет отключить таймер:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```